# Time Record Calculations in PHP

Tags: php

I have a database table full of time records and I need to calculate the quantity of hours that exist between them...

A time record has the following fields: `'created'` (i.e. 2017:08:30 11:15:00) and `'direction'` (i.e. 1 represents "clock in" and "0" represents "clock out"). So I need to set a start and end date, then select all time records within that time frame and calculate the quantity of hours worked (the quantity of hours that exist between the records where `direction=0` and `direction=1`).

Any idea how to create the logic for this? The result must be a measurement of "hours" in decimal format (1 decimal place, i.e. '26.7' hours).

I started by establishing variables:

```
$query_start_date = "2017-08-29 00:00:00";
$query_end_date = "2017-08-30 23:59:59";
```

Let's assume these are the time records that exist in that time frame:

```
time record 1: 'created'="2017-08-29 08:00:00", 'direction'=1;
time record 2: 'created'="2017-08-29 16:30:00", 'direction'=0;
time record 3: 'created'="2017-08-30 08:00:00", 'direction'=1;
time record 4: 'created'="2017-08-30 16:00:00", 'direction'=0;
```

But I don't know how to begin the calculation. Do I select the records first and assign each record to a variable as an array...? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't get the `direction`-param. if you have a start and an end time, why not just have two columns?

Comment: Are the records always in sequence of direction 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0... Are there holes? (eg: two consecutive 0s?

Comment: Yes, records will always be in alternating sequence, either 0, 1, 0, 1 or 1, 0, 1, 0 depending on where the line is drawn with the start/end dates

Comment: Magnus - each time record serves a purpose, it either represents the date/time an employee clocked in (started work) or clocked out (finished work). So the 'direction' parameter keeps track of that.

Answer (score 0):

Make start and end time in two columns:

```
SELECT 
   created as start, 
   (select created from test t2 where t2.created > t.created
      and direction = 1 order by created limit 1) as end 
   FROM `test` t where direction = 0
```

conunt time difference:

```
select TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end, start))/60/60 as diff, start, end from
  (SELECT 
     created as start, 
     (select created from test t2 where 
        t2.created > t.created 
        and direction = 1 order by created limit 1) as end 
   FROM `test` t where direction = 0) intervals
```

and finally count sum:

```
select sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end, start))/60/60) as total from
  (SELECT 
     created as start, 
     (select created from test t2 where 
        t2.created > t.created 
        and direction = 1 order by created limit 1) as end 
   FROM `test` t where direction = 0) intervals
```